How can I update ZData in a bar3 plot?
I'm trying to update the ZData of a bar3 plot:
z = [[1, 2]; [3, 4]];
z_new = [[1, 2]; [3, 3]];
h = bar3(z);% works fine until here

set(h, 'ZData', z_new);

I then get following errors:
Warning: Error creating or updating Surface
 Error in value of property  ZData
 Array is wrong shape or size 
Warning: Error creating or updating Surface
 Error in value of property  ZData
 Array is wrong shape or size 

They don't crash the program but the data of the existing plot gets deleted instead of overwritten.
I don't understand why this happens, since the matrices are obviously the same size.


I don't understand why this happens, since the matrices are obviously the same size.

They are not of the same size. bar3 creates a custom ZData entry from the z argument provided. Displaying the ZData entry for z=[[1, 2]; [3, 4]];
h.ZData

ans =

   NaN     0     0   NaN
     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     0
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN     0     0   NaN
     0     3     3     0
     0     3     3     0
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN


ans =

   NaN     0     0   NaN
     0     2     2     0
     0     2     2     0
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN     0     0   NaN
     0     4     4     0
     0     4     4     0
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN     0     0   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

You could update ZData by constructing a matrix in the above format and filling z_new data in the correct places and it should work. If your intention is to just overwrite the old plot you're better off using h = bar3(z_new);

Pevan's answer explains why you can't directly set ZData using the same matrix which you would input to bar3, but here is an example of how you can manipulate z_new using a helper function to set the ZData directly without having to redraw a new bar3 object.
See the comments for some more detail of each step:
z = [[1, 2]; [3, 4]];
z_new = [[1, 2]; [3, 3]];
h = bar3(z);% works fine until here

setz3( h, z_new )

function setz3( h, z )
    % Helper function to create and apply the required surface matrices to
    % the surface array which bar3 returns, for changing the z heights
    % using the same syntax as bar3 takes for input
    % First, make a template which contains the correct surface for each
    % bar but just of height 1, then loop to modify each surface
    zz = NaN(6,4);                            % initialise to NaN
    zz([2,3,7,10,11,13,16,17,20,21]) = 0;     % edge points to 0
    zz([8,9,14,15]) = 1;                      % interior points to 1
    for ii = 1:size(z,2)
        zi = zz.*reshape(z(:,ii),1,1,[]);         % scale by bar heights
        zi = reshape(permute(zi,[1,3,2]),[],4,1); % stack all bar heights
        h(ii).ZData = zi;                         % assign to surface
    end
end

